# Azure Application Gateway - Rewrite Links returned

Tags: url-rewriting, azure-application-gateway

I'm attempting to use Application Gateway to serve a language for a webpage on a separate domain.

The setup is as follows:
domain.com is running the entire site, default language is english
domain.com/de serves german versions of the pages

What I'd like to do is use domain.de to serve the german pages.

Setting the override backend path (/de/) works perfectly in order to serve the pages, but inside the page there's a lot of links that turns into domain.de/de/pageTitle. I'd like to remove /de/ from theese links, but can't seem to figure out how.

Anyone that can point me in the correct direction?

Answer (score 0):

***With URL rewrite capability in Application Gateway, you can:***

Rewrite the `host name`, `path` and `query string of the request URL`

Choose to rewrite the URL of all requests on a listener or only those requests which match one or more of the conditions you set. These conditions are based on the request and response properties (request, header, response header and server variables).

Choose to route the request (select the backend pool) based on either the original URL or the rewritten URL

To learn how to rewrite URL with Application Gateway using Azure portal, see ***[here](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/application-gateway/rewrite-url-portal.md).***

***[!NOTE] HTTP header and URL rewrite features are only available for the Application Gateway v2 SKU***

For more information you can follow this ***[MS Document](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/application-gateway/rewrite-http-headers-url.md#rewrite-http-headers-and-url-with-application-gateway)***